# cxf jsonprovider ignore $ sign from response

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

after upgrading cxf to 3.1.4 I get the following JSON.

```
{"record_type":{"desc":"Staff","$":"STAFF"}}
```

How can I get rid from the '$' sign?

I use a customize provider which extends the following class.

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider
```

With the following flags

```
    setIgnoreNamespaces(true);
    setDropRootElement(true);
    setDropCollectionWrapperElement(true);
    setSerializeAsArray(true);
    setSupportUnwrapped(true);
    setAttributesToElements(true);
    setValidateOutput(true);
```

Thanks